# Getting max value from a row containing zeros,negative

Tags: mysql, max

I have a query which calculate the avg I have used union all in the query so to get the data i have finally used max function.

As union returns result something like this:-

```
col 1      col2
1            0
2            0
3            0
4            0
0            -1
0            2
0            3
0            4
```

so when i do max it returns me 0 instead of -1

my query goes like this :-

```
select max(col1), max(col2)
from mytbl
```

i get resultset like this:-

```
max(col1)      max(col2)
1               0
2               2
3               3
4               4
```

Can anyone tell me how can i can max from 0 and a negative value in a query.

Comment: Please tell us more about the table definition and the full query. Maybe a union all isn't the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this using `MAX()` (although I think that you should think about the whole query more), try replacing the zeros (which apparently "do not count") by `NULL`. `MAX()` will disregard the `NULL`'s and compute the maximum of the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
select max(t1.col1), max(t2.col2) from mytbl t1 left join mytbl t2 on t2.col2 <= 0 where t1.col1 <= 0;
```

Your query

```
select max(col1), max(col2)
from mytbl
```

can not select multiple rows, because MAX is aggregation function.

Comment: Probably the full query is not given. I guess there is a GROUP BY involved.